# Issues with io/ioutil

Tags: go, exec, pid, ioutils

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to grab processes id's with my limited knowledge on golang and the below is what I've come up with:

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("tasklist.exe")
    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    f, err := os.Create("data.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer f.Close()

    val := out
    data := []byte(val)

    _, err2 := f.Write(data)

    if err2 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err2)
    }

    val2 := " and red fox\n"
    data2 := []byte(val2)

    var idx int64 = int64(len(data))

    _, err3 := f.WriteAt(data2, idx)

    if err3 != nil {
        log.Fatal(err3)
    }

    fmt.Println("done")
    /* ioutil.ReadFile returns []byte, error */
    explorer, err := ioutil.ReadFile("data.txt")
    /* ... omitted error check..and please add ... */
    /* find index of newline */
    file := string(data)
    line := 0
    /* func Split(s, sep string) []string */
    temp := strings.Split(file, "\n")

    for _, item := range temp {
        fmt.Println("[", line, "]\t", item)
        line++
    }
    fmt.Println(explorer)
}
```

My Main issue is that i keep running into the same wall where ioutil won't let me assign a value before reading the file.

Is anyone able to help me out here?

Comment: To Preface, for this example, I want to grab the line with the explorer.exe PID on it from the Tasklist, if there is an easier way to do this please let me know

Comment: Try removing `defer f.Close()` and adding `f.Close()` on the line before `fmt.Println("done")`. My initial thought was that you are trying to open data.txt again (with `ioutil.ReadFile()`) while it's already open from the `os.Create()` call. I assume you're on Windows? The example worked as-is for me on linux (my data was "hello world", however), but I maybe file handles work different in your environment (ie Windows doesn't allow you to open and already open file, or doesn't allow a single process to have multiple handles on the same file, etc).

Comment: @BennyJobigan Thank you for your comment, please allow me to confirm a few things. - I am indeed on windows so yes a single process can only have 1 handle to a file at once, the issue I’m having is with having the file already open so closing and reopening this could work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Lewis Well, my thought was wrong. I ran your example on a windows 10 VM and didn't get any errors... just a bunch of lines of my processes from the for-loop over `temp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's not working in your original example, but a few minutes of experimentation and reading the [docs for tasklist.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist) gave me something better. The main improvement is letting `tasklist.exe` do the heavy lifting by giving it args.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // original command:
    // tasklist.exe /nh /fo csv /fi "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe"
    // /nh = no header
    // /fo csv = format output to csv
    // /fi = filter on query
    //
    // run tasklist.exe /? for more info
    //
    // sample output:
    // "explorer.exe","4860","Console","1","102,240 K"

    // start tasklist with args to do the hard work for us.
    // we want CSV output (easier to parse), and let tasklist search for explorer.exe.
    // obviously you could seach for another task name instead of explorer.exe.
    //
    // the key thing here is that the query ("IMAGENAME ...") doesn't
    // require " when passed as an arg because exec.Command()
    // will apparently handle that for you 
    // (quoting like `"IMAGENAME..."` produced an error from Output() )
    cmd := exec.Command("tasklist.exe", "/nh", "/fo", "csv", "/fi", "IMAGENAME eq explorer.exe")
    out, err := cmd.Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // create a csv reader around the output of the above command.
    // then use ReadAll() to split the csv into [][]string.. a slice
    // of "lines" (aka records, rows) where each line is a slice of 
    // csv "columns" (aka fields, entries).
    r := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(out))
    lines, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // the result may have multiple processes (eg svchost.exe) or none.
    for _, line := range lines {
        // the process id is at index 1 as a string.
        // do whatever you need to do with the result.
        fmt.Println(line[1])
    }
}
```